# Why XCode Storyboard not able to recognize unwind function in some UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I notice in some case, XCode is not able to recognize unwind function in some `UIViewController`.

For instance, the following `UIViewController` has the following unwind functions.

1. unwindFromShop
2. unwindFromPreference

But, when I try to use StoryBoard to build unwind segue, it cannot recognize such functions in that view controller.

[image]

My current only workaround, is the select other unwind segue in other view controller, then rename `Action` accordingly.

[image]

There is no issue, to trigger run the unwind function, during simulator run.

I try to clean, build, restart XCode. Somehow, XCode still not able to recognize the unwind functions declared in that particular view controller.

I was wondering, is this bug in XCode? I am using **Version 13.3.1 (13E500a)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to workaround the issue, by renaming `ViewController` class name to `MainViewController`.

After the renaming, the XCode seems to able to recognize the unwind functions again.